# Элемент Toolbar-a с счётчиком

Tags: java, android

Делаю кнопку toolbar-a с счётчиком, но когда я налаживаю на элемент свое поле в меню, при помощи:

```
android:actionLayout="@layout/toolbar_badge"
```

или

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/toolbar_badge"
```

Кнопка перестаёт реагировать на нажатия.

Реализацию использую от [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39496466/7609373)

Answer (score 0):

Хотел сначала удалить вопрос, но может кто столкнётся. Плохо когда не знаешь английского и игнорируешь чтение комментариев. Там в комментариях обсуждается эта же проблема, и единственное решение, это установить слушатель нажатия на TextView:

```
    tvShoppingBasket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) { 
                       ваш исполняемый код 
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Лучше на сам контейнер, который содержит TextView :)

Comment: Согласен, сам только что заметил, только в таком случае на этот контейнер необходимо добавить:     android:clickable="true"